# How to reveal a mural that was painted over

Tags: repair, painting

A mural I painted years ago was recently painted over by 'accident' and the owners would like it restored.  I painted it in latex and acrylics.  Looks like they used white enamel.  Is it possible to save the mural?

Comment: Not really a DIY question - more a specialty artist question.  You could just repaint it...

Comment: Paint a new one, you have a nice new blank canvas.